# Beam + Dataflow abnormally slow on a small data set

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We try to execute heavy calculation on simple data set (about 18k rows).

- Input data are rows in a BigQuery table, two columns: ID (Integer) and DATA (String). The DATA values are of the form **"1#2#3#4#..."** with 36 values.
- Ouput data are the same form, DATA are just transformed by an algorithm.
  It's a OneToOne transformation.

We expect this amount of data is treated in a few minutes, but it does not work well, there are errors if several workers are instancied (See the errors after the code sample).
My research so far seems to be heading towards the notion of "shuffle" but I don't understand where the problem lies.

Here is a light version of the class (I've removed the write part, the behaviour remains the same):

```java
    public class MyClass {
    
    static MyService myService = new MyService();
    
    static class ExtractDataFn extends DoFn<TableRow, KV<Long, String>> {
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
            Long id = Long.parseLong((String) c.element().get("ID"));  
            String data = (String) c.element().get("DATA");         
            c.output(KV.of(id, data));
        }
    }
    
    public interface Options extends PipelineOptions {
        String getInput();
        void setInput(String value);
    
        @Default.Enum("EXPORT")
        TypedRead.Method getReadMethod();
        void setReadMethod(TypedRead.Method value);

        @Validation.Required
        String getOutput();
        void setOutput(String value);
    }

    static void run(Options options) {
        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

        PCollection<TableRow> rowsFromBigQuery = p.apply(
                BigQueryIO.readTableRows().from(options.getInput()).withMethod(options.getReadMethod())
        );              
        
        PCollection<KV<Long, String>> inputdata = rowsFromBigQuery.apply(ParDo.of(new ExtractDataFn()));
        PCollection<KV<Long, String>> outputData = applyTransform(inputdata);
        // Here goes the part where data are written in a BQ table
        p.run().waitUntilFinish();
    }

    static PCollection<KV<Long, String>> applyTransform(PCollection<KV<Long, String>> inputData) {      
        PCollection<KV<Long, String>> out = inputData.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<Long, String>, KV<Long, String>> () {
                        
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(@Element KV<Long, String> element, OutputReceiver<KV<Long, String>> receiver, ProcessContext c) {
                modifiedData = myService.calculate(element.getValue()); // here is the time consuming operation             
                receiver.output(KV.of(element.getKey(), modifiedData));
            }
          }))
        ;
        return out;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Options options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(Options.class);
        run(options);
    }
}
```

In the GCP Logs console we can see the number of workers increasing up to 10, during about 5 minutes, it decreases to 3 or 4, and then we have this kind of messages (several hundreds of them), and CPU is about 0%:

```
Proposing dynamic split of work unit myproject;2020-10-06_06_18_27-12689839210406435299;1231063355075246317 at {"fractionConsumed":0.5,"position":{"shufflePosition":"f_8A_wD_AAAB"}}
```

and

```
Operation ongoing in step BigQueryIO.Write/BatchLoads/SinglePartitionsReshuffle/GroupByKey/Read for at least 05m00s without outputting or completing in state read-shuffle at app//org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.ApplianceShuffleReader.readIncludingPosition(Native Method)
```

If we let it run it finishes in error of this kind :

```
Error message from worker: java.lang.RuntimeException: unexpected org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.CachingShuffleBatchReader.read(CachingShuffleBatchReader.java:77)
```

If I modify the myService.calculate method to be faster, all the data are treated by only one worker and there is no problem. The problem seems to occured only when treatments are parallelized.

Thank you for your help

PS: please, before to close this subject, ask for clarifications if needed

Comment: When the issue is related to the number of workers in the job, it is often caused by the network communication between the VMs. If there are no [firewall rules that allow enough communication between them](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/routes-firewall), it will present a similar behavior as the one you described, e.g. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60260552/7517757). If there's no issue with the firewall rules, please share the beam SDK being used and the configuration of your dataflow job

Comment: Thank you, it was a network issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64259658/apache-beam-dataflow-too-slow-for-only-18k-data/64559844#64559844